# How do a mount a NAS (WD, MyBookLive) so i can add media to a plex server?

Tags: server, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

How do I add/mount my exsisting NAS drive (WD,MybookLive) so that I can add the folder to my plex server?

As I understand it (and this is day1 of me using Linux)

I have to add a line in `fstab` to mount the drive.

`$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

So I have added the following line:

`//192.168.0.100/Public/videos/ /media/Plex cifs guest 0 0`

I have three shares on my NAS, a public share called "Public". I have several folders there. One of them called videos has... all the video files.

Public doesn't need an account/password and I have created a user called guest with no password and with access to Public.

To test the mount I type

`$ sudo mount -a`

Which gives the response:

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I can check my log, which states:

```
Oct 19 22:33:28 Jon-Server kernel: [ 3084.106615] 
No dialect specified on mount. 
Default has changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). 
To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.
```

So from what I understand, I have to do two things, maybe:

- one is specify the version of cifs
- the other is to add in a line about the language/locale to use

But I don't know how to parse that into one line or what I should even do now.

Thanks

Comment: You have come a long way in one day ;-) And mount messages are notoriously hard to figure out. Do you have `cifs-utils` installed?

Comment: yeah got that installed.

Comment: Try removing the `/` at the end of `//192.168.0.100/Public/videos/`.

Comment: To specify the version, just add the option `vers=1.0` to your options as `guest,vers=1.0`

Comment: How do you know where the commers go?

Comment: The documentation for `fstab` says: "       The fourth field (fs_mntops).
              This field describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.

              It  is  formatted as a comma-separated list of options." You can see it by doing `man fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally with the post and comments above I could figure it out (MyBookLive connection, Ubuntu 18.04)
The bit that helped was the SMB version (vers=1.0). For the sake of clarity:

```
//192.168.1.55/Videos /mnt/wdvideos cifs guest,vers=1.0 0 0
```