# I don't see a 3TB disk

Tags: partitioning, automount, disk-management, mountpoint

I have 2 disks in my PC: one is 1TB where I have installed Lubuntu and another one 3TB (empty for now).
I see both disks correctly in Disks, Gparted and KDE partition manager. But I can not make it visible to my system (eg File Manager, Double Commaner).

**My objectives are**
1) create 1 partition in the 3TB disk
2) assign a label and mount point
3) use it "as usual" from any file manager.

Can you help me step by step? I tried with all three mentioned programs but I can't really make it work.

This is the output of `sudo blkid`

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="6362-D394" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="4da2498d-8faf-4604-8e66-e9afdc2f8781"
/dev/sda2: UUID="9387db92-e022-4078-8fae-bf9359cc9edc" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2fa7df9a-40f3-4f7d-8d76-22f28b3a8127"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="3TB-Data" UUID="c994cec3-c8d9-4ad5-8d50-a1be4793c133" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="3TB" PARTUUID="b386733a-67ee-48bc-ad94-656fd1b3e736"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
```

This is the output of `lsblk -f`

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core18/1288
loop1  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/snapd/5754
loop2  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/core18/1279
loop3  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
loop4  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
loop5  squashfs                                                     0   100% /snap/libreoffice/163
sda                                                                          
├─sda1 vfat              6362-D394                             291.7M     3% /boot/efi
└─sda2 ext4              9387db92-e022-4078-8fae-bf9359cc9edc  856.8G     1% /
sdb                                                                          
└─sdb1 ext4     3TB-Data c994cec3-c8d9-4ad5-8d50-a1be4793c133
```

And here the current contents of /etc/fstab file:

```
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=6362-D394  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0   2   
UUID=9387db92-e022-4078-8fae-bf9359cc9edc   /   ext4    defaults    0   1   
/dev/sdb1   /media/user01/2TB disk  ext4    users   0   0
```

As you can see, the last line of the fstab file looks a little weird, right? I guess I should change the fstab file. To avoid modifying fstab manually, I tried Disk's "Mount at system startup" option. But I guess I will need to do it manually, right?

Here I show the information shown by Disks for each disk and partition:
[image: 1TB disk, space before partitions]
[image: 1TB disk, partition 1]
[image: 1TB disk, partition 2]
[image: 1TB disk, space after partitions]
[image: 3TB disk, only partition (notice it is not mounted)]

Comment: Please run `lsblk -f` and add it to your question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do a mount a NAS (WD, MyBookLive) so i can add media to a plex server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085382/how-do-a-mount-a-nas-wd-mybooklive-so-i-can-add-media-to-a-plex-server)

Comment: You have to gpt partition it, add a partition (or more), format partition(s). If ext4 you also have to give yourself ownership & permissions. And best then to add entry to fstab to auto mount on reboot. If a second install or something you do not auto mount I like to label partition so when mounted it has descriptive name. I do not like Disks as it may not use correct parameters (many use since easy). Better to use template/example and adjust for your specifics
https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup

Comment: Did you format it with a MBR partition table, or a GPT partition table?

Comment: heynnema, as far as I remember it was created as a GPT; oldfred thanks, it may be in the correct path. I included more information just to be sure before manually editing fstab; Graham: nope. Thanks; Geroge Udosen: thanks, I did.

Comment: Your disk is not mounted. Check this [guide](https://tecadmin.net/mount-and-unmount-filesystem-in-linux/).

Comment: @Ifly777 thanks, I checked that and by using `mount -a` I discovered there was actually an error in my fstab file. So I corrected that and everything is fine now :)  So this is probably the closest to a correct answer. How to make it more visible?

Answer (score 0):

**If the issue lies with partitioning**

to format a partition with full control, first open any terminal.

lsblk and fstab shows that **/dev/sdb is your 3TB drive**.
so first we shall **create the partition table** (blueprint for future houses)

then we shall **create the first partition**(the first house built using the blueprint)

then we shall **create the filesystem of the partition**(describes how things should be placed and organized within this house.)

**your drive requires a GPT partition table** because of its size, and we want a single partition for the entire device.

```
$sudo parted /dev/sdb              - will ask for password and start parted aiming only at your 3TB drive
(parted) mktable gpt               - will turn it into a GPT table
(parted) rm 1                      - will remove the existing partition
(parted) mkpart primary 0% 100%    - will create a new partition covering 100% of space
(parted) quit                      - brings you back to terminal
```

**Now we need to create a filesystem within this partition**. you have many options here, the most common being ext4 NTFS Fat32 exFat(Fat64)

**Exfat** is best if you plan on using this drive with windows, mac, and linux machines

**NTFS** is best if you plan on using only windows

**ext4** is best if you plan on using only linux

**Pick one of these**

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdb1       - will format partition 1 to fat32
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1            - to ext4
```

**If instead you want exFat**

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse     - will install exfat functionallity and tools
sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1           - will format it to exfat
```

at this point we have a fully functioning partition that **should be picked up as a mountable filesystem**.

if you would like to name it use one of these commands

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 NAMEHERE      - ext4
sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdb1 NAMEHERE    - ntfs
sudo exfatlabel /dev/sdb1 NAMEHERE   - exFat
```

if you follow and understand this without solving your issue, then the problem does not lie within partitioning.

a simple way to test is if all drives act like this than its not the drives themselves, if only this single one does this than more than likely its a problem with partitioning or possibly a failing hard drive that needs to be replaced.

P.S. you can manually mount this in the exact way the system does by using this command

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1
```